# Excel VBA localisation issue - WIN 8.1 Enterprise, Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

I have a problem with file using VBA macros created in GER version of Excel. This macro is testing the pivot table item for "Alle", but when someone opens the file in EN version, the pivot table item is obviously not "Alle" but "All" so the macro doesn't work. Same issue is with "leer" - "blank" or "#N/A" - "#NV" etc. Did anyone face this issue and is there any developed solution? Is it possible to lock the language setting of the workbook so that the "Alle" are not changed to "All"? Or any other working solution?

Comment: No, you can't tie local settings to a workbook. I'm not saying what you want isn't possible, just that I know you can't do that.

Comment: You should be able to check the locale settings through the Windows API. This might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318103(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim loc As Long
loc = Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)

If loc = 1033 Then
    'english code here
ElseIf loc = 1031 Then
    'german code here
End If
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664) is the MSDN link for locale IDs.